# How to implement ReadXml for SomeClass : IList<IFoo> where all instances of IFoo are IFoo<T> of varying T

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, ixmlserializable

I have a class that I need to serialize/deserialize, and I'm half way there - I have serialization functional, resulting in the below XML. However, since I'm implementing `IXmlSerializable` myself, I'm uncertain what an implementation of `ReadXml` should look like, given that `SomeGenericClass<T>` was serialized using attribute-based flagging rather than an explicit implementation if `IXmlSerializable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<FooContainer FooName="DoSomething">
  <SomeGenericClassOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Value="Foobar" Name="firstParam" Description="First Paramater Serialized" />
  <SomeGenericClassOfInt32 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Value="10000" Name="nextParam" Description="Second Serialized parameter" />
</FooContainer>
```

Which I want to serialize back into an instance of:

```
public class FooContainer : IList<ISomeGenericClassBase>, IXmlSerializable
{
     public string FooName {get;set;}

     void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) {
         var serializer = XmlSerializer.FromTypes(new Type[]{SomeGenericBaseClass})[0];
         this
             .Select(item=>SomeGenericClassBase.ConvertToMe(item))
             .ToList()
             .ForEach(item=>serializer.Serialize(writer, item));
     }

     // IList Implementation omitted - wraps a private List<ISomeGenericClassBase>
}
```

Where the list will contain instances along these lines:

```
public interface ISomeGenericClassBase
{
}

public interface ISomeGenericBaseClass<T> : ISomeGenericBaseClass 
{
} 

public class SomeGenericClassBase : ISomeGenericClassBase
{
    public static SomeGenericClassBase ConvertToMe(ISomeGenericClassBase target) {
        return new SomeGenericClassBase() {Property1 = target.Property1; Property2 = target.Property2}
    }

    public static ISomeGenericBaseClass ExpantToTyped(SomeGenericClassBase target) {
        // Implementation omitted - converts a base class instance to a generic instance by working out the generic type from saved data and reconstructing
    }
}

public class SomeGenericClass<T> : SomeGenericClassBase, ISomeGenericBaseClass<T>
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description{get;set;}

    [XmlAttribute]
    public T Value {get;set;}

    [XmlElement("")]
    public T[] ValidOptions {get;set;}

}
```

EDIT: Expanded the implementation - realised as it was, it didn't illustrate the problem correctly

Core issue is that I want to be able to serialize items that only implement the interface, even if I only get back `SomeGenericClassBase` instances. Per the approach used in the `ExpandToTyped` method, I'm expecting consumers of the class to save sufficient data in *their* implementations that allow the resulting classes to be converted back into their original form as required. So yes, there's a loss of fidelity, but it's one I can live with in exchange for the flexibility of using a list of interfaces instead of a list of base classes.

Comment: Why would you use xml attributes for serializing, but not for deserializing?

Comment: Sorry about that - just re-read what I asked, and I can see why you'd have the question. I've expanded the question to be more illustrative of exactly what I'm trying to do. Summary reason, though, is that the list is of interfaces, not base classes.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, though - actually pointed me in the right direction! Solution was to scrap IXmlSerializable and use a serializable converter class - will type it up in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to sidestep the issue (IXmlSerializable.ReadXml looks quite painful anyway, e.g. for collections). What I eventually did is scrap IXmlSerializable, and instead generate a class along the lines of the below.

Please note that whilst this approach works, it's currently quite error prone if the serializable instance is used for anything other than serialization - synchronization is maintained ONLY when `SerializationTarget` is set or retrieved. When it's set, we convert existing parameters to appropriate instances and add them to a serializable list. When it's retrieved, if it's null, we inflate from whatever was in the current value.

However, if FooContainer changes after the creation of this object, it won't maintain that synchronization and what gets serialized will be out of date. This is largely because I'm lazy and don't want to implement `IList<SomeGenericClassBase>` again to override the `Add` and `Remove` methods (though this would be the more robust approach).

```
public class FooContainerSerializable
{
    public FooContainerSerializable() {}
    public FooContainerSerializable(FooContainer serializationTarget) 
    {
        this.SerializationTarget = serializationTarget;
    }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public FooContainer SerializationTarget
    {
        get {
            if (_SerializationTarget == null)
            {
                _SerializationTarget = new FooContainer();

                // Copy across extant collection properties here
                this.Parameters.ForEach(item=>_SerializationTarget.Add(item));
            }
            return _SerializationTarget;
        }
        set {
            // Synchronize this entity's entries here
            _SerializationTarget = value;
            _SerializationTarget.ForEach(item=>this.Parameters.Add(item.Deflate()));
        }
    }
    private FooContainer _SerializationTarget;

    [XmlElement]
    public string FooName {
        get {return this.SerializationTarget.FooName;}
        set {this.SerializationTarget.FooName = value;}
    }

    [XmlElement]
    public List<SomeGenericClassBase> Parameters {
        get {return _Parameters ?? (_Parameters = new List<SomeGenericClassBase>());}
        set {_Parameters = value;}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option if you are willing to use an abstract class instead of an interface in your collection definition. You'd also need to declare all the derived types of `SomeGenericClassBase` using `XmlInclude` attributes. I'm thinking this wouldn't be too bad if there are just a handful of types you'd use with this class.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "FooContainer")]
public class FooContainer : List<SomeGenericClassBase>
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string FooName { get; set; }
}    

[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeGenericClass<string>))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(SomeGenericClass<int>))]
public abstract class SomeGenericClassBase
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class SomeGenericClass<T> : SomeGenericClassBase
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public T Value { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public T[] ValidOptions { get; set; }
}

class Class1
{
    public static void Run()
    {
        var f = new FooContainer()
        {
            new SomeGenericClass<string> {  Name = "firstParam", Description = "First Paramater Serialized", Value = "Foobar"},
            new SomeGenericClass<int>  {  Name = "nextParam", Description = "Second Serialized parameter",  Value = 10000 }
        };

        f.FooName = "DoSomething";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(f.GetType());            
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // Serialize
        using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter(sb))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, f);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb);

        // Deserialize
        using(StringReader reader = new StringReader(sb.ToString()))
        {
            FooContainer f2 = (FooContainer)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

This would serialize to the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<FooContainer xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SomeGenericClassBase xsi:type="SomeGenericClassOfString" Name="firstParam" Description="First Paramater Serialized" Value="Foobar" />
  <SomeGenericClassBase xsi:type="SomeGenericClassOfInt32" Name="nextParam" Description="Second Serialized parameter" Value="10000" />
</FooContainer>
```

Deserialization maintains full fidelity.

Comment: Interesting approach - and a good bit cleaner than mine, I think. In thinking that with a static method that handles unknown types under an `[XmlInclude(SomeGenericClass<object>)] ` it could probably work just as well (plus a corresponding `Expand()` method to try to convert back to T). Will give it a shot and see how it works. Lamentably, whilst I expect a pretty limited set of types, I can't guarantee consumers of the class won't try other ones, and I'd like to be able to handle them if possible!